# OSX two-factor Authentication for ARD and VNC

Tags: mac-osx, vnc, two-factor

I am looking at the possibility to add two-factor authentication , using linOTP and Radius, to all network logins ( Servers, Workstations, Switches, etc... )
So far I have been able to set this up for Linux, Windows,Switches, VPN, etc...
However, I cant find any documentation or clues on how to enable 2FA on OSX , for VNC/ARD.
2FA for SSH is already working on OSX.
I dont want 2FA for local access, only remote. So adding 2FA via /etc/pam.d/login is not an option I think.

Regards, Koen

Comment: What's the question, again?

Comment: Hi Hunter, Sorry if my question was unclear :-) The question is : How to implement two-factor authentication on OSX for Remote Desktop.